# is some thing missing for python json requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

i just test the requests .
i install it via pip install requests
and i user `r=requests.get("http://localhost/json")`
this is simple data
{"info":"yes"} for this json file
and i use 
info=r.json["info"]
it show error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mysns/bbsns/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    info=r.json()["info"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 741, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

someone can tell me,where is the problem?
looks like the json can not be use in my system

Comment: What happens if you simply use `info=r.json()`?

Comment: @hjpotter92: it is the `r.json()` call that throws the exception.

Comment: What does `r.text` show? What is `r.status_code`? Anything in `r.headers` that looks of relevance?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `info = r.json()["info"]` as opposed to `r.json["info"]`?

Comment: for info=r.json() ,it show the same errors

Comment: looks like the problem is json ,if i do not parse the json data,everything works well

Comment: @s16h: that's what the OP already *has*.

Comment: @zzlettle: the exception shows you don't have a JSON response. Please show us what `r.text` is.